# Genetic algorithm in univeristy timetabling

Tags: scheduling, genetic-algorithm

Can anybody help me understand how to apply a GA in timetabling?

Right now I understand the steps of a GA, but don't know how to implement them in my project.

Can somebody guide me? If there is any pseudocode or links to help me it will be very much appreciated.

This is my university project. I'm not asking for working code, just some idea n pseudocode on how to implement it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Solving Timetable Problem by Genetic Algorithm and Heuristic Search Case Study: Universitas Pelita Harapan Timetable](http://www.intechopen.com/download/get/type/pdfs/id/30303)

Answer (score 0):

Transform the problem into a integer representation using an array to represent the chromosomes in the population.

Example {1, 2 , 5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 5}

The index in the array represents courses and the number at each index represents the time slot that the course is assigned to on a day. Random populations can then be created and evaluated based on a fitness function that would take into consideration the students associated with each course, course size, and any other constraint that may be present. I have used this approach to solving a university final examination timetable and it has worked well.